# Can I delete ‘it’ in ‘Everything was as he remembered it.’?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Everything was as he remembered it.

Can I delete **it** in the sentence above?

I feel it is weird to contain **it** in the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is not "weird" to include *it*, but it is not necessary.**

An Ngram seems to show a recent rise in popularity of this type of omission:

[image]

**Q:** How was everything?

**A:** It was all as he remembered (it).

Can you see how *it* is a bit redundant here? What other pronoun or noun could sensibly be considered implicit and would drastically change the meaning of the sentence? The subject has already been stated once.

**Most (if not all) fluent speakers of English would understand either way. It is up to you.**

[Click here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=kCNHX-rsNYSY_QaugZTQCg&q=%22was+as+he+remembered.%22&oq=%22was+as+he+remembered.%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...38716.39217.0.40153.4.4.0.0.0.0.122.406.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.3SsXmfQBXxs.) to see the results of a Google Books search, which shows that both forms are in use.

Comment: Google Books, like Google, flatly ignores punctuation, so your Google Books link doesn't hold water. The Ngram viewer seems to be capable of handling punctuation by processing it like a word.

Comment: @EddieKal I did not know that, but looking through the results gives many good examples nonetheless. The search may have been flawed, but what was found is great. I was not attempting to show (with that link) the difference in popularity, it was simply to show OP that both *are* in use.

Comment: The Ngram is surprising to me - I would have expected that *as he remembered* was the older usage.

Comment: The speaker has a mental image of something he knew long ago - he _remembers it_ as looking a certain way, and finds that it still looks like that.

Comment: May you tell what does **it** represent？

Comment: @Y.zeng "It" refers to "Everything", which is the subject of the sentence. You could technically say, "Everything was as he remembered everything" but that is redundant.